# Kotlin QUEUE or QUEUE using database autoincrement or combining both?

Tags: mysql, kotlin, queue

Working with `kotlin` queue is very easy but it store data in device. So my choice is `Mysql` database that is universal.

Do you recommend just `Mysql` for (shopping) queue? if so what is the job of `queue` in `kotlin`?

Is there a way to get data from `kotlin` queue then store it in `Mysql` server just like a real line queue?

I ask this because I am sure about confidence, errorless and accuracy of `kotlin` queue but I don't know any thing about Mysql queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A queue in Kotlin is primarily used for in-memory storage, meaning the data is stored in the device's memory and not persisted.

On the other hand, MySQL is a widely used relational database management system that offers a more robust and scalable solution for data storage.

When it comes to managing an online system, using MySQL as the data storage solution is a recommended approach. MySQL provides a universal and reliable platform for storing and retrieving data, making it suitable for various applications.

The role of a queue in Kotlin, or any programming language, is to maintain a first-in-first-out (FIFO) order for elements. This means that the elements are processed in the same order they were added to the queue.